# Чем принципиально отличаются прилагательные "концептуальный", "концептный", "концепционный" и "концепциозный"?

Tags: словообразование, семантика, прилагательные, синонимы, смысл

Чаще всего встречается "концептуальный", реже — "концептный", ещё реже (или даже уже за гранью допустимого) — "концепционный" и "концепциозный"...

В чём ключевое смысловое различие этих прилагательных? Отличаются ли они так же, как существительные "концепция" и "концепт", и как с ними связаны (см. [здесь](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/12776/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%82-vs-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F))?

Comment: Вы, кажется, не поняли с первого раза, что Грамма.ру — не авторитетный ресурс, а один из десятков вопросоответных сайтов. Нам совершенно всё равно, что там отвечают. В дальнейшем я буду расценивать упоминание неавторитетных вопросоответных сайтов как спам и вычищать их из вопросов.

Comment: Ладно, не буду их ответы приводить больше.

Comment: Почему, кстати, мне порой убирают кавычки в "Грамма.ру", "Нацкорпус" и т. п.? Вы тоже их без кавычек пишете...

Comment: Почему вам убирают — не знаю. Лично я не ставлю, потому что не вижу смысла громоздить кавычки, когда и так ясно, что название сайта. Ставлю только с родовым словом: портал "Грамота.ру".

Comment: @Shi Komarishe А в каких толковых словарях эти слова упоминаются как синонимы? Концепционный еще можно где-то найти, а двух других слов в словарях вообще нет (концептный и концепциозный). Похоже, Грамма.ру отписалась и на этот раз, да еще не очень удачно. Если слов нет в общих словарях, то они должны быть в специализированных. А если и там их нет, то это уже авторская лексика, и тогда считывать значение слова надо с морфемного состава. Все-таки справочной службе надо называть вещи своими именами, а нам – критически оценивать информацию из любых источников.

Comment: М-да, видимо, "Грамма.ру" имела в виду, что отличия этих слов не настолько сушественны (или по крайней мере видны только в контексте), чтобы однозначно их разграничить. Мол, тогда автор сам волен решать в своём тексте, в каком контексте их употреблять и как разграничить...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Значение слов определяется **по словарю**.

**КОНЦЕПТ**, -а; м. [лат. conceptus ― понятие, мысль, представление] 1. **Лог.** Содержание **понятия**. 2. **Книжн. =Концепция** (2 зн.). К. статьи, доклада, экономических реформ. <Концептуальный (см.).

**КОНЦЕПЦИЯ**, -и; ж. [лат. conceptio] 1. **Система** связанных между собой и вытекающих один из другого взглядов на то или иное явление. Научная к. Выработать концепцию. 2. **Основная мысль**, идея произведения, сочинения и т.п. К. статьи. Художественная к. романа.

**КОНЦЕПТУАЛЬНЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; -лен, -льна, -льно. 1. Лог. к Концепт (1 зн.). К-ие признаки понятия. К-ое ядро значения слова. 2. Книжн. Содержащий концепцию, основанный на концепции. К-ое мышление. К-ые разработки. // Сущностный, содержательный. К-ая критика. К. анализ. <Концептуальность, -и; ж. (2 зн.).

2. Мы видим, что ***концепт*** ― это специальный термин в логике, обозначающий понятие, а ***концепция*** используется в книжной речи и имеет значение система взглядов и понятий (иногда в этом же значении используется и *концепт*).
3. Прилагательное ***концептуальный*** является основным и применяется во всех случаях, то есть может относиться к обоим словам (*концепт* и *концепция*). Три остальных прилагательных встречаются редко, в орфографическом словаре есть только ***концепционный***. Что можно о них сказать?
4. ***Концептный*** ― лишнее, как мне думается, слово, у него нет значения, отличного от прилагательного *концептуальный*, а фонетика не слишком удачная. ***Концепционный*** и ***концепциозный*** также не имеют нового смысла, отличного от указанного в общем толковом словаре.

Можно обратить внимание на **суффикс ОЗН (ЕЗН),** который имеет дополнительное значение изобилия или наделенности в большей степени тем, что названо мотивирующим словом (помпезный, религиозный, также в медицине гриппозный, тифозный).

5. Однако все эти прилагательные следует отнести **к специальной терминологии**, и тогда их значение нужно смотреть в специализированных словарях или определять по тексту. Дать определение только по морфемному составу слов  вряд ли возможно.

Comment: Мне кажется, что надо внести правку в 4 часть: или написать суффиксы -ОЗН-/-ЕЗН-, или убрать прилагательное *помп**езн**ый*, так как в нем суффикс -ЕЗН-.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. В толковом словаре  словообразовательных единиц у Ефремовой указаны суффиксы ОЗН (ЕЗН), они обычно составляют пару (как ОВ/ЕВ и др.), там же приведен этот пример. Я посмотрела в Викисловаре этимологию слова "помпезный". Происходит от франц. pompeux (pompeuse) «помпезный, пышный», далее из pompe «торжественность, великолепие, помпа», по образцу вульг. лат. pomposus, из класс. лат. pompa. Получается,что формант ЕЗН вроде бы присутствует уже там, у нас он повторяется: 1. ПОМПА, -ы; ж. Внешняя, показная пышность, торжественность. Принять кого-л. с помпой.

Answer (score 1):

- Концепциозный = порождающий концепты/концепции
- Концептуальный = являющийся концепцией в той или иной мере, но не обязательно оперирующий концепциями
- Концептный = оперирующий концептами, но не обязательно сам являющийся концепцией
- Концепционный = принадлежащий какой-то концепции, но не обязательно являющийся ею

Тут самим носителям языка трудно сформулировать разницу. Я бы ориентировался только на ЧАСТО употребляемые словосочетания и анализировал только их.